# blinking line in web page

Tags: html, css

[image: this is the web page]

when i click on the page a line equal to the height of table start blinking on left side of the page.

i want to remove that blinking 
any one can help me ?

Comment: can you give us a working example?

Comment: If possible can you paste the code or have you used blink method of javascript anywhere?

Comment: @Ankit no have havn't use any javascript method, wht i feel it can b solved with table properties,

Comment: @ Damien-at-SF , working example mean?

Comment: What OS are you using?  I only ask because I've noticed this behavior in Ubuntu with Firefox, but not in Windows.

Comment: @bilal A copy of the site that does what you are describing so that we can see first hand what's going on :)

Comment: i am using Firefox with Windows XP

Comment: @Bilal Just check in other browsers and see if these problem persists or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IE Developer Toolbar or Firebug or Chrome dev-tools, to figure our what is occupying that empty pixel.
Likely some CSS style sheet or something in the background is peeking through and that starts changing for whatever reason, when you do certain things on page.

Again, something like Firebug in Firefox should help you track it down.